# Can't change the background colour of td only in grey rows in dataTable

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatable

I have a dataTable and in one column of my table I am showing a value which is boolean. I want to change the background colour of the td according to the value of this boolean; green when it's true and red when it's false. Here is my html.

```
<table id="myTable" class="table table-striped m-b-none" data-ride="datatables">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                               <th>Food</th>
                               <th>Edible</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach (var item in Model)
                            {<tr>                                        
                                    <td>@item.FoodName</td>
                                    <td class="@String.Format("alert {0}", ((item.IsEdible) ? "alert-success" : "alert-danger"))">@(item.IsEdible? "Edible" : "Not Edible")</td>                                        
                                </tr>}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

[only white rows are affected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x14mN.jpg)

And here is the js:

```
  $('#myTable').dataTable({               

            "bProcessing": true,
            "sDom": "<'row'<'col-sm-6'l><'col-sm-6'f>r>t<'row'<'col-sm-6'i><'col-sm-6'p>>",               
            "iDisplayLength": 10,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",

            }
```

Table striped css:

```
 .table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > td,
.table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > th {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
```

Can't change the class of td which is inside grey row in dataTable. I think I need to dive in BaseStyle of dataTable but couldn't figure it out how to do it. Any help?

Comment: Give us an example of the TD in plain html, might be a simple CSS change. How are you changing to green?

Comment: And add the relevant CSS rules to your question

Comment: Instead of providing a link (that will probably not work in a not so-distant future) with the picture of your code, provide a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or a `snippet` of your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't included your CSS rules in your question, this is an educated guess:

Whatever CSS rule is getting applied for the `table-striped` class is taking priority over the `alert-success` and `alert-danger` classes.

It's either from the order of the CSS rules (rules lower in the file take precedence over previous rules), or the rule using the `table-striped` class may be a more [specific](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) rule.

Given the rule you just added to your question, you can add the following rule to cover the striped rows:

```
.table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > td.alert-success,
.table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > th.alert-success {
      background-color: green;  
}

.table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > td.alert-danger,
.table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > th.alert-danger{
      background-color: red;  
}
```

Replacing the `green` and `red` with whatever the `background-color` is from the appropriate `alert` classes.

Comment: Before asking, I couldn't see that table-striped is overriting my selection of class. Thank you very much. I added the above css and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Load a custom css file in the end of your css list. Then add some custom css for `alert-success` or `alert-danger` in that file. This will take priority over `table-stripped` class rules.

Answer (score 0):

To do this JS driven, so that you can call this and update the data accordingly basis on data change:

```
$("#myTable td").each(function(){
if($(this).text()==true){

        $(this).css('background-color','#090');
    }else{
     $(this).css('background-color','#900');
}
})
```

Comment: I ended up applying css, but thanks for your reply. It is a nice alternative solution.

Comment: The answer you have marked straight away set odd and even rows without any logic on the data of the table cells...while in question you said you want to change background based on cell value

Comment: Actually  applying a new css is more logical because whenever in any table I want to change the background color of a boolean value, I will give the alert-success class to **true** booleans, and alert-warning to **false** booleans,as you can see in my question. Because of that with new css it's all under control. I dont need to write js for every table.

And I am not sending the boolean value to the client side as **true** or **false**; if it's true I am changing it something meaningful, like 'Edible' above. In this case your solution is not very efficient for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you included **table-striped** class in your table then this problem will occur. As per my solution don't use this class then it will work as you want.